# Sort a dictonary according to every ith element in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

**EDIT- UPDATED Question :**

Just to elaborate my question more, I am adding more details in **test1Res** :

I have a dictionary named test1Res which has some product names as 'Key' for the dictionary and test results of that product as values to the keys.

There are 6 test performed (6 criteria) and hence each 'Value' in the dictionary' is a list of 6 integers.

```
test1Res = {'Wrap': [3,7,13,142,16,193], 'Baby':[3,29,16,146,16,110], 'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65],'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0],'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
```

I want to sort the dictionary such that:

- Dictionary should be in descending order of their 'Value' - List of 6 integers:

  - First step - Sort according to first criteria 'a' i.e. 0th element of each list.

O/P :

```
test1Res = {'Wrap': [3,7,13,142,16,193], 'Baby':[3,29,16,146,16,110], 'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65],'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0],'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
```

(Same as Input.) ( Sort performed considering every 0th element of the value.)

- Second Step - For each lists whose 0th element is similar,(i.e. results of test 'a' for the similar products), sort in descending order according to result of second test - 'b'.

O/P:

```
test1Res = {'Baby':[3,29,16,146,16,110], 'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0], 'Wrap': [3,7,13,142,16,193], 'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65], 'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
```

Note that now 'Wrap', 'Baby', 'Goon' and 'Marz' has been sorted according to point 2. Sorting performed considering every 1st positioned element of lists, **whose 0th element were similiar.**
Now, as 1st element of 'Wrap' and 'Goon' is similar, it should sort Only these 2 key-value pair according to 2nd element in next steps.

- Next steps : Similarly check for every (i+1)th element of list whose i th element is similar.

**Final Output** :

```
test1Res = { 'Baby':[3,29,16,146,16,110], 'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0], 'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65],  'Wrap': [3,7,13,142,16,193], 'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
```

So far i have tried many approaches but only able to sort it upto step 2, that too by brute force. ( O(n^3)) which is not acceptable due to time complexity.)

Ignore any syntax error.

**ORIGINAL Question** :

I have some products and lab test results stored in a list, and whole as a dict as show below:

```
test1Res = {'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65],'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0],'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
```

Each value of list represents result of a particular test, say test `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]`. So, for 'Goon', result of test `a` is 3 and so on.

What I want to do is sort the **test1Res** in such a way that:

- It is decreasing in Ranking, where ranking is based on the criteria
  a-g.

Output should look something like :

```
test1Res = {'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0],'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65],'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
```

Here, First it should look for 0th element in list of each key. If it is similar, then and then only it should look for second element of that lists, then third, then fourth and up to last one.

Comment: Python dictionary doesn't guarantee the order of key value pairs.
Look into orderedDict, or use list of dictionaries like  [{'name' : 'Marz', 'data' : [3, 9,14, 8, 56, 0]}, {'name' : 'Goon', 'data' : [3,7,22,41,88,65]} ]

Comment: @therj you're wrong, python dictionaries are ordered

Comment: Is it just me or is `'Marz':[1,9,...` in the initial data and `'Marz':[3,9,` in the final result?

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Only in Python 3.6 and greater are dictionaries ordered.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo I wasn't aware. Discovered it arrived with 3.6 in CPython, and implemeted in Python 3.7 as a language feature. Cheers!

Comment: @MrGeek Updated the Fatal, My Apology.

Comment: @user3386109 I am new to programming field, having majors in Biology. Not Familiar with the Computer's terminology. I have updated the question, and hope now i have made my point. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dict` is guaranteed to maintain insertion order only in CPython 3.6 and greater so it is best to use an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

test1Res = {'Wrap': [3,7,13,142,16,193], 'Baby':[3,29,16,146,16,110], 'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65],'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0],'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
d = OrderedDict((sorted(test1Res.items(), key=lambda it: it[1], reverse=True)))
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
OrderedDict([('Baby', [3, 29, 16, 146, 16, 110]), ('Marz', [3, 9, 14, 8, 56, 0]), ('Goon', [3, 7, 22, 41, 88, 65]), ('Wrap', [3, 7, 13, 142, 16, 193], ('Adax', [2, 2, 28, 13, 79, 39])])
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but i had an issue communicating my needs for output. I have updated the output requirements and this seems less likely to meet that requirements. Sorry for the inconvenience, but if you can invest some more time updating the answer as per the requirements, please!!

Comment: My algorithm, which remains unchanged (only the test data has changed), has always done what I believe you are asking, which is to use successive elements of the list as necessary to break ties. It does this by doing a *list compare* and that is the way a Python list compare works: [6, 3, 2] > [6, 3, 1]

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the values and create a new dictionary with the new order:

```
>>> dict(sorted(test1Res.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
{'Goon': [3, 7, 22, 41, 88, 65], 'Adax': [2, 2, 28, 13, 79, 39], 'Marz': [1, 9, 14, 8, 56, 0]}
```

You provided two different dictionaries, here's the result with the second one:

```
>>> test1Res = {'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0],'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65],'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
>>> dict(sorted(test1Res.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
{'Marz': [3, 9, 14, 8, 56, 0], 'Goon': [3, 7, 22, 41, 88, 65], 'Adax': [2, 2, 28, 13, 79, 39]}
```

Comment: I have updated the Fatal - 'Marz' : [3,9,14,8,56,0] instead of [1, 9,14, 8, 56, 0]. My apologies for that. Also, i have tried this approach, but not able to get what i want in Output. I have made serious clarifications  in the question in terms of required output, please if you can invest some more time to update accordingly!!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to import [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator) module:

```
test1Res = {'Goon':[3,7,22,41,88,65],'Marz':[3,9,14,8,56,0],'Adax':[2,2,28,13,79,39]}
result = dict(sorted(test1Res.items(), key=lambda elem: elem[1], reversed=True))
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'Adax': [2, 2, 28, 13, 79, 39], 'Goon': [3, 7, 22, 41, 88, 65], 'Marz': [3, 9, 14, 8, 56, 0]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but i believe i had an issue communicating my requirements in output. I have clarified my requirements, if you can invest some more time updating according to the requirements, please!!

Comment: @Bunny it is basically the same as @Ronald Aaronson's answer, without using `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Oh my bad! I really appreciate your efforts. I am a newbie in python, and wasn't aware of this!